# The effect that influences each participant due to the contribution

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

A positive effect that influences each of the participants due to their contribution, participation, and teamwork.

For example, **person A** and **person B** are doing the project closely together, which **helps** and **educates** both of them, while at the same time **moves the project forward**, how can this positive, ______ effect be called?

**P.S.** Please, tell me if you do not understand clearly what I mean, I will try to rephrase. Thank you!

Comment: I am personally having trouble understanding what it is you mean... You're looking for one word that simultaneously means helps, educates and moves the project forward?

Comment: I think *learning experience* for the people. (Potentially *praxis* if you want to use a fancy but obscure term.)  Is that about right?  But "___ effect" calls for an adjective like *enlightening* or *enriching*.

Comment: @bendl It's the effect that affects each participant due to their contribution. You contribute to the project, I contribute and from doing that we get the effect that affects each of us, something like "each-side-affective".

Comment: It sounds like you're suggesting something along the lines of *mutually beneficial*. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @bendl **Mutual**! Exactly! Thank you! Could you write a separate answer, so that I could accept it as the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mutually beneficial**

Mutually beneficial implies that two or more parties are involved in some activity, and that their involvement positively affects each party individually.

Answer (score 1):

synergy ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/synergy))

> the interaction of elements that when combined produce a total effect that is greater than the sum of the individual elements, contributions, etc.

Comment: It was a very close one, that I managed to found by myself, but not exact. Forgot to mention it in my post. But thank you!